How can I retrieve original model parameters from a LbfgsLogisticRegression-trained model?
I have chosen to use LbfgsLogisticRegression because it is retrainable (can be trained on further data without losing existing model). (link)
My first batch of data trains very well with the usual Fit call:
var estimator = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", nameof(SampleDataEntry.Features))
.Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.LbfgsLogisticRegression(labelColumnName: "name_match", featureColumnName: nameof(SampleDataEntry.Features)));

However when it comes to retraining, I am apparently supposed to call Fit(IDataView, LinearModelParameters). I have the IDataView, but am struggling to get the LinearModelParameters. Microsoft's documentation gives the following code sample for a different algorithm:
// Extract trained model parameters
LinearRegressionModelParameters originalModelParameters =
    ((ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>)trainedModel).Model as LinearRegressionModelParameters;

However, when I try to adapt this to retrieve my own model parameters, I get a range of casting failures. Investigating the model object in watch mode, I see that it doesn't even have a Model property as implied in the code sample. It has a .LastTransformer property, which in turn contains .Model.
.LastTransformer has type
Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryPredictionTransformer<Microsoft.ML.Calibrators.CalibratedModelParametersBase<Microsoft.ML.Trainers.LinearBinaryModelParameters, Microsoft.ML.Calibrators.PlattCalibrator>>
.LastTransformer.Model has type
Microsoft.ML.Calibrators.ParameterMixingCalibratedModelParameters<Microsoft.ML.Trainers.LinearBinaryModelParameters, Microsoft.ML.Calibrators.PlattCalibrator>
Opening up that model, we find a .SubModel property, which is of type
Microsoft.ML.Trainers.LinearBinaryModelParameters
However, if I retrieve that set of parameters, they do not include basic information such as the label field, so retraining fails.
Can anyone point me to code samples / tutorials, or explain where I could look for those original parameters?
Here's that final snippet of code that isn't working:
LinearBinaryModelParameters originalModelParameters = ((TransformerChain<BinaryPredictionTransformer<CalibratedModelParametersBase<LinearBinaryModelParameters, PlattCalibrator>>>)model).LastTransformer.Model.SubModel as LinearBinaryModelParameters;
return mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.LbfgsLogisticRegression().Fit(splitTrainSet, originalModelParameters);

